# Data is becoming duplicate in next.js

Tags: api, next.js

I have data from API. And I need modals for delete and edit to it. but When I open the modal window, the data is duplicated after refreshing

```
const [category, setCategory] = useState()
let myValue = []
const getCategory = async () => {
    const id = window.localStorage.getItem('categoryId')
    await axios.get(`${API_URL}/categories/${id}`, {
        headers: {
            Authorization: token,
            Accept: 'application/json'
        },
    })
        .then(res => {
            const category = res.data
            console.log(category.data, 'shu');
            myValue.push(category.data)
            console.log(myValue, 'value');
            setCategory(myValue)
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

This is code for fetching data. And This is code for modals.

```
const [openDelete, setOpenDelete] = useState(-1);
const handleOpenDelete = (elem) => {
    setOpenDelete(elem.id);
    // console.log(index);
}
const handleCloseDelete = () => {
    setOpenDelete(-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to push your data to the `myValue` Array.
Instead of `myValue.push(category.data)`, better set your store directly like `setCategory(category.data)`.

Comment: I try to it but when I write like this it didn't work after refresh